# Can't use the insert() method

Tags: rust, hashmap

I have a very strange problem: When i create a HashMap with HashMap::new(), everything works right, but when i create a hashmap with HashMap::capacity_and_hasher, i can't use insert method

the error:

```
    |
 93 | map.insert(1,2);
    |     ^^^^^^ method cannot be called on `HashMap<_, _, &RandomState>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
    |
   = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `&RandomState: BuildHasher`
```

The code:

```rust
let s = RandomState::new();
let mut map = HashMap::with_hasher(&s);
map.insert(1,2);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass your object `s` of type `RandomState` **by value**. [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=720a31eb575e16169f8010ffa8914e3b)

Notice `HashMap::with_hasher(s);`

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::collections::hash_map::RandomState;

fn main() {
    let s = RandomState::new();
    let mut map = HashMap::with_hasher(s);
    map.insert(1,2);
}
```

The very same is suggested by [documentation of `with_hasher`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#examples-3)